# Bash. Intersection with 2 files

Tags: bash

I have a huge files with 2 columns of data and a second huge file with 3 columns of data. I want to extract the 3rd column from the second file based on the first one. This means that if I have the following first file:

```
A B
C V
```

and the second:

```
A B 3
C V 4
B G 6
```

I should get in the output file:

```
A B 3
C V 4
```

Is that possible with a shell script?

Comment: For sorted files, `join` should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with AWK:

```
% awk 'NR == FNR {a[$0] = 1; next}a[$1 FS $2]' file1 file2
A B 3
C V 4
```

Breakdown:

```
NR == FNR { # Run block for file1 only
  a[$0] = 1 # Store line in associative array
  next      # Skip next block
}
a[$1 FS $2] # Print lines from file2 if they are in associative array
            # Same as writing a[$1 FS $2] { print $0 }
```

Another way with grep is:

```
grep -f file1 file2
```

which will try to match each line in file1 with lines from file2. This will not start the search at the beginning of the string though.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same with grep command also . But might take little longer.

```
$ cat file1.txt
A B
C V
$ cat file2.txt
A B 3
B G 6
C V 4
$
```

Below is the grep version for the same :

```
$ while read line ; do grep "^$line" file2.txt ; done < file1.txt
A B 3
C V 4
$
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple `cat` and `grep` combination works in my zsh.

```
cat 2.txt | grep "$(cat 1.txt)"
```

or

```
grep "$(cat 1.txt)" 2.txt
```

> A B 3
>
> C V 4